# Unable to install Python Requests module in windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, pycharm

Unable to install and configure Python Requests module in Pycharm in windows 10. Getting errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you use CNTLM Authentication ?

Comment: Can you pip install any package? It looks like your network is forbidding the connection

Answer (score 1):

you are working behind a proxy (probably corporate environment) so you need to setup the following environment variable in your PC.

Apparently your "proxy.com" is not a valid proxy. Get the proper info from your IT department.

```
HTTP_PROXY
HTTPS_PROXY
```

Comment: https://superuser.com/a/1163035 has some answers about determining current proxy settings under windows

Answer (score 0):

If python is added to your `PATH` then can use:

```
pip install package-name
```

Answer (score 0):

in pycharm: 
File->setting->project:example->click on the plus button on the right side of packages and add selenium-requests

Answer (score 0):

You can add flags trusted host and try the following command:

python -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.python.org --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org requests